# Eigenvalues of matrix products

Tags: stochastic-processes, limits-and-convergence, eigenvalues

Hi my problem is with row stochastic matrices. Its known that if we keep multiplying this row stochastic matrices, we will get a rank one row stochastic matrix. Rank one means that all the rows has the same values. This named the convergence of the matrix.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJwRT.jpg "Matrices"

I put an image of my matrix A[0] and a circular shifted (1 circular shift means that you take the last Coulomb and put it to first place and shift all others) version A[1]. My simulations shows that instead of getting the power of the same matrix A[0]^2 , if we multiply it with shifted version of it, A[1]xA[0], we convergence faster.

Sorry for my language and bad presentation of the my problem. I will give more explanations if needed. Plz ask me. I really need to solve this problem.

Thx everyone for their time.

Comment: Some suggestions: (1) describe your general framework. It's not clear what "convergence" or "better" means. (2) use more formulas. Even things like "shifted version of $A$" can be ambiguous. (3) use more LaTeX. Something is seriously wrong with the formatting of those matrices, they aren't even square.

Comment: I will do it right away. My bad :(. Thx for the suggestions.